# How to handle filterd result during continously refreshing data?

Tags: datatable

I have no issue to use DataTable, to filter its data and put it into a DefaultView.
The thing is even I use original DataTable or creation of DefaultView to present the filtered data my time dependent operation is getting constantly input that is refreshed in DataTable that is bind to DataGridView and when the filter is active and values are updated row-wise it is refreshed. So it results in this specific visual thing that rows that are filtered out get inserted back but not completely just in 1 column and if I select this row in DataGridView it pushes out an error System.IndexOutoFRangeException.
If no filter is active all is fine.
I need an advise what I need to do to reach my goal:

Even if a filter is active the values should be updated in DataTable (works already) that refreshes DataGridView without a "glitch"[glitched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUMyr.png) so I can select a row without getting the aboves exception.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

The trick looks simple that solves the glitch too.

myDT = new DataTable();
myDV = new DataView(myDT);

bind the View to DataGridView.